# how to make callBack to get the content of time and minute from timePickerFragment in android

Tags: android, callback

I want to get the hour and minute and bind it to other textViews, I know here we have to use callBack but I don't know how to use it in this case.

```
public class CheckoutFragment extends Fragment {


    public CheckoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    FragmentCheckoutBinding binding;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentCheckoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
  binding.timePickerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment2();
                timePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "time picker");
   
            }
        });

binding.getRoot();
}


    public static class TimePickerFragment2 extends DialogFragment {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(i) + " : " + Integer.toString(i1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }, hour, minute, false);
        }
    }

}
```

I have used callBacks but I don't know how to use it in this case because in callBacks we pass callBack in function as parameter but here in which function we can pass? I don't need code, just explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You use **Fragment Result API** to create the communication between two fragments
for example

In onCreate of your **CheckoutFragment**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setFragmentResultListener("TimePickerRequestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
        val result = bundle.getString("time")
    }
}
```

In **onTimeSet** function

```
setFragmentResult("TimePickerRequestKey", bundleOf("time" to result))
```

You can find more information in below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result

Comment: i did but i don't know why it is not working.